# Retrieve Records added into a Data Extension on the last hour using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, datetime, ssjs

I have a Filtered Data Extension "Audience Segmentation - Python Developers" with the following fields: 
 - SubscriberKey
 - Name
 - ProgrammaticLanguage
 - DateAdded (default value: Current Date)

I need to **retrieve the records inserted in the last hour into a Data Extension using SSJS**. I tried to use SQL, but I cannot create a SQL activity related to a Filtered Data Extension.

I´ve been looking unsuccesfully for a solution.

Have any of you faced this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying your filtered Data Extension with SQL, you should query the original one. DE filter is just a UI representation of what in fact is a SQL query in the backend.

The timestamps you have will also not be updated when records enter the filtered DE, only when they entered the original one.

So your best approach would be to replicate the filter in SQL, adding the criteria of *DateAdded > now() - 1 hour*